# Generic model defined and used by different Microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

We Have a scenario where we are monitoring machines so called endpoints.We receive the data for events happening in a machine in kafka through some mechanism. 
Two different microservices are listening to the topic to process the data. Both services have different purpose

1. **Alerting** : For generating alerts based on the data in the topic.
2. **Asset**: Showing Machine Event Data coming in the topic to our clients.

The problem that i see is that we have defined a **common model** for below cases as a library:

- To serialize the data at machines to be sent to kafka for the services to be consumed.
- To deserialize the data consumed by the two services mentioned above (Alerting and Asset)

I feel this is a wrong way to define models in Microservice environment , because that introduces coupling among sub-domains which are not directly related to each other and are representing different bounded context. In the above case

- **Alerting**(Bounded context): Generate alerts based on the data.(Business capability or sub-domain)
- **Asset**(Bounded context): Showing Machine Event Data to clients (another sub-domain)

Also the common model as a library breaks the below requirements:

- Basic requirement of Bounded context that they must be autonomous , change in the common model will affect either of the services.
- Microservices should be independently deployable, change in the model will mandate both the services deployed separately even if the change wasn't of any use for any one of the services.

The Solution i feel apt for this scenario is to have separate models instead of a common model for both the services as a representation of the incoming data in the topic or use the data in one service by requesting to another service and create an association between the two services.

Need to understand which is the correct approach for the micro services.

Comment: "Basic requirement of Bounded context that they must be autonomous" - not exactly: the practice of Context Mapping described in the DDD book proposes different strategies to integrate BC's. You might also find [that presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-microservices-2016) interesting.

Comment: You are right, but again its integration and collaboration between bounded context , not creating unnecessary dependency between bounded contexts  by sharing domain model which changes differently for different bounded contexts.Where BC1 has not relation with BC2 and how it changes.

Comment: I don't really get the point of your question then. Are you just complaining that you can't have your cake (a shared model) and eat it (have it be independently evolvable for each BC)? It seemed pretty obvious to me right from the start...

Comment: Context Mapping has a wide range of options to choose from, including "Separate Ways" (i.e. no sharing/integration). A tradeoff has to be made anyway, you just need to decide on it.

Comment: Just my 2c: "Autonomous Business Components" probably relate more to the cohesion and deployment of a bounded context / microservice rather than to dependencies.

Comment: Yes by Autonomous Bounded context i meant independent deployment,making changes to the bounded context without affecting other non related contexts. If we share the model it devoid these requirements.

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes so we had this shared cake and i felt that it is creating dependency between unrelated BCs and a bottleneck. So yes thats what is happening in our current implementation and i was debating against it.So wanted to understand the general opinion

Comment: @user3278744 there's no general opinion about it, just local, context-dependent tradeoffs. The DDD book has a whole chapter on these.

Comment: @ guillaume31 , hmmm , so it was not just about DDD it was about DDD thinking while writing Microservice, so that we can keep the ideologies of Microservice held properly in the system and make the design loosely coupled enough....  Thanks a lot for the response ....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a bit that may be unique to your situation that I don't see at this point which *may* mean that you need to *not* have a common library but from what I can tell there is nothing wrong with your existing implementation that has a common library.

In some instances you may even have a `Shared Kernel` which is exactly that.

This is not coupling different bounded contexts together but you *are* relying on some bit of functionality that, when it changes, may result in your endpoint requiring some rework and redeployment.  The fact that more than one bounded context relies on that functionality is inconsequential.

In the same way I may be using some `Nuget` package that is upgraded with a breaking major version resulting in an upgrade to that version requiring a redeployment of my endpoint.  Although in this case it would probably be the actual endpoint and not be directly related to the bounded context domain model.

Comment: Shared kernel are generally employed for cross cutting concerns like authentication etc which if changes its across all services. But shared model is not a desirable approach because change in one service will make another to change and that create unnecessary dependency between services

Comment: Rather there effectively can be different model for each service as they are not in anyways dependent on each other. When the number of services depending on the model is small its fine, but gradually it will create pains and not a good way to design Microservices , i believe...

Comment: The example that you shared is more of a behavioural function that is shared as a library between services and that absolutely makes sense , but sharing entity or value objects or rather domain models across Microservices does not seem a very good way to design Microservice. Whats your thoughts...

Comment: I guess it is going to depend on the "communication direction"... how you use that shared bit (basically what @guillaume31 mentioned in his comment).  Something like  `Identity & Access Control` can quite easily be a generic sub-domain that you would quite easily share across bounded contexts.  I guess you need to pick your poison :) --- but to be honest unless you are in an early stage of development where changes are frequent there really shouldn't be the type of disruption that you allude to.

Comment: Its not early stage now, its almost quite sometime these services are built and IMO even if its early stage or latter stage this kind of cohesion through shared model among unrelated BC should be absolutely avoided , so that we don't gradually turn the environment into a Distributed monolith.The model keeps evolving irrespective of the tenure of the services.